# Sort javascript objects and combine objects into an array

Tags: javascript

I have the following implementation and its functional

https://jsfiddle.net/9mv6w0da/

Here is implementation:

```
function groupBy(arr, f) {
  var result = {};
  arr.forEach(function(elem) {
    var fElem = f(elem),
        list = result[fElem] || [];
    list.push(elem);
    result[fElem] = list;
  });
  return result;
}

function objToArray(obj) {
  var result = [];
  for(k in obj) {
    result.push(obj[k]);
  }
  return result;
}


var allData = dataSet.reduce(function(a, b) { return a.concat(b) });
var grouped = objToArray(groupBy(allData, function(data) { return data.color + "#" + data.weight }));

console.log(grouped);
```

**Input**

```
dataSet[0]= [
    {color:"yellow",weight:12}
   ,{color:"yellow",weight:13}
   ,{color:"yellow",weight:11}
   ,{color:"red",weight:15}
   ,{color:"red",weight:18}
];          
dataSet[1]= [
    {color:"yellow",weight:22}
   ,{color:"yellow",weight:32}
   ,{color:"red",weight:3}
   ,{color:"red",weight:9}
   ,{color:"blue",weight:10}
   ,{color:"blue",weight:8}
];
```

**Current Output** - grouped based on color

```
an[0]=[
    {color:"yellow",weight:12}
   ,{color:"yellow",weight:13}
   ,{color:"yellow",weight:11}
   ,{color:"yellow",weight:22}
   ,{color:"yellow",weight:32}
]
an[1]=[
    {color:"red",weight:15}
   ,{color:"red",weight:18}
   ,{color:"red",weight:3}
   ,{color:"red",weight:9}
]
an[2]=[{color:"blue",weight:10},{color:"blue",weight:8}]
```

However, I would like to have the following output to put weight values in an array rather than having a multiple javascript objects.

**Desired Output**

```
an[0]=[{color:"yellow",weight:[12,13,11,22,32]}]
an[1]=[{color:"red",weight:[15,18,3,9]}]
an[2]=[{color:"blue",weight:[10,8]}]
```

Comment: What have you tried? You can't expect us to write all the code for you, right?

Comment: I have put my jsfiddle in the question.

Comment: @casillas - a fiddle is great but the link won't be available as long as this question will be.  future users need to know what you've tried to do in writing for your question to be useful for others.

Comment: I have added my code here as well.

Comment: Are you sure that's the output you want? A nice object where the colors are keys might be better and easier to handle.

Comment: Yes, if I get my desired output, then I could able to reach my desired prototype: http://dojo.telerik.com/aJExe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var dataSet = [
    [
        {color:"yellow",weight:12}
       ,{color:"yellow",weight:13}
       ,{color:"yellow",weight:11}
       ,{color:"red",weight:15}
       ,{color:"red",weight:18}
    ],          
    [
        {color:"yellow",weight:22}
       ,{color:"yellow",weight:32}
       ,{color:"red",weight:3}
       ,{color:"red",weight:9}
       ,{color:"blue",weight:10}
       ,{color:"blue",weight:8}
    ]
];

function indexByColor (input) {
    var output = {};
    for (var i in input) {
        for (var j in input[i]) {
            var x = input[i][j];
            if (output[x.color] === undefined) output[x.color] = {
                color: x.color, 
                weight: [],
            };  
            output[x.color].weight.push(x.weight);
        };  
    };  
    return Object.keys(output).map(function(c){
            return output[c];
    });     
};  

console.log (indexByColor(dataSet));
```

Here is the jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/f3syta4f/

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<script>
    var dataSet=[];
    dataSet[0]=[
        {color: "yellow", weight: 12}
        , {color: "yellow", weight: 13}
        , {color: "yellow", weight: 11}
        , {color: "red", weight: 15}
        , {color: "red", weight: 18}
    ];
    dataSet[1]=[
        {color: "yellow", weight: 22}
        , {color: "yellow", weight: 32}
        , {color: "red", weight: 3}
        , {color: "red", weight: 9}
        , {color: "blue", weight: 10}
        , {color: "blue", weight: 8}
    ];
    var colorArr=[];
    var finalArr=[];
    for(var i=0; i < dataSet.length; i++)
    {
        (function(j)
        {
            for(var i=0; i < dataSet[j].length; i++)
            {
                if(colorArr.indexOf(dataSet[j][i]['color']) != -1)
                {
                    var index=getIndexByValue(finalArr, 'color', dataSet[j][i]['color']);
                    finalArr[index]['weight'].push(dataSet[j][i]['weight']);
                }
                else
                {
                    finalArr.push({'color': dataSet[j][i]['color']});
                    colorArr.push(dataSet[j][i]['color']);
                    var index=getIndexByValue(finalArr, 'color', dataSet[j][i]['color']);
                    finalArr[index]['weight']=[dataSet[j][i]['weight']];
                }
            }
        })(i);
    }
    function getIndexByValue(array, key, value)
    {
        for(var i=0; i < array.length; i++)
        {
            if(array[i][key] === value)
            {
                return i;
            }
        }
    }
    console.log(finalArr);
</script>
```